# Write IPTable rules

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, network-security

How to write IPTable rules such that the administrator on 128.238.66.2 has ssh access to the firewall and no one else is allowed access?

Is it like: iptables –A INPUT –s 128.238.66.2 –j ACCEPT?

Comment: `iptables` deals with only ports. For your `UNIX` user use your `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` which is basically private keys found under `.ssh` folder under `HOME` directory to utilize user ability outside the world using through `SSH` by `known_hosts`. You may form `~\.ssh\authorized_keys` with `.pub`.

Comment: I would like to let you know one thing that the command `ip` wasn't there on `UNIX` based `distros` years back down the line, the true thing is however the firewall command `iptables` has the ability to do any `service` based `ingress` `egress` rules. This is something that more things been brought in now so. It is not completely to. Maybe even before. And I do not know how exact `iptables` commands fits too for `SSH`, some manual intervention required on both sides of the `node` as described by, other than that.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this (please be aware that if the IP is wrong, you're locked out):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 128.238.66.2 --dport ssh -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport ssh -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

When we say about iptable it is that it bounds with Kernel. The function of iptable is for Setting_Up Firewall.

And to understand its basics you should understand it in, from ground level rather knocking with your sequence of absurd commands as you end-up scribbling & scratching head. Following step by step standard instruction will not be scenario always. SO, lets understand it.

There are three level segregation when we talk about iptable.

```
Level-1: Rule

Level-2: Chain

Level-3: Table
```

Lets see one by one now,

```
Rules are-> ACCEPT, DROP, QUEUE, RETURN

Chains are-> Input, Output, Forward, Pre Routing, Post Routing

Tables are-> Filter Table (Default), NAT Table, RAW Table, Mangle Table
```

Coming Next Firewalls by generations of improvement can be said like,

```
1) Packet Filtering Firewall

2) Stateful Firewall

3) Application Layer Firewall

4) Proxies Firewall.
```

Comment: This is as per OSFY magazine (Open Source For You). It had looked good. So shared the same. I hope it gives the good readability and helps as well.